# How to remove merging message on source code control from Visual Studio Code?

Tags: laravel, git, visual-studio-code

after merging branches, this message persists, even after it has been commited and working on other branches! Advice on how to clear it pls!?

[image: message on VSC]

Comment: wow and think I have descriptive branch names

Comment: @rioV8 company rules

Comment: If at all possible, try not to obscure key parts of a question behind an image. (See [ask])

Comment: It would be better to put the error text directly in the article

Answer (score 1):

This message is located in the input field where you type your commit message.
So just select all the text there and press `Delete` key.